# Cannot go into weight paint mode while in pose mode

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, weight-painting, rigid-body-simulation

So im posing my rig and I can select bones to transform but when hitting the drop down menu the "weight paint" option does not show up while I'm in pose mode.

[image]

Comment: This is because you have your armature selected and you cannot weight paint or texture paint your bones, only mesh can give you options to weight paint... You first need to deselect armature, select your body mesh and then weight paint

Comment: @MikoCG But I cant select body meshes while in pose mode

Comment: Yes you cannot, that's why I said, deselect armature(go to object mode) and then select your body mesh

Comment: @MikoCG So I selected the bodyy part mesh but how do I know which bone I am weight painting? Isn't there a way to select the bone I want to weight paint as well as the body mesh?

Comment: Yes there is, you are selecting them with vertex groups in that mesh while weight painting, this is why it is important to name your bones correctly so that you will know what is what